# How to Regex in a script to gzip log files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, gzip

i would like to gzip log files but i cannot work out how to run a regex expression in my command.

My Log file look like this, they roll every hour.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 aus nds    191353 Sep 28 01:59 fubar.log.20150928-01
-rw-r--r-- 1 aus nds    191058 Sep 28 02:59 fubar.log.20150928-02
-rw-r--r-- 1 aus nds    190991 Sep 28 03:59 fubar.log.20150928-03
-rw-r--r-- 1 aus nds    191388 Sep 28 04:59 fubar.log.20150928-04
```

script.

```
FUBAR_DATE=$(date -d "days ago"  +"%Y%m%d ")
fubar_file="/apps/fubar/logs/fubar.log."$AUS_DATE"-^[0-9]"
/bin/gzip $fubar_file
```

i have tried a few varients on using the regex but without success, can you see the simple error in my code.
Thanks in advace

Comment: A general hint: logfile rotation and compression should not be done by a web application. it is a maintenance task, thus it should be triggered and controlled by the system, not the application. Take a look at the "logrotate" package all distributions offer. That way you decouple maintenance from the actual application logic which clearly makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did:

```
$ fubar_file="./fubar.log."${FUBAR_DATE%% }"-[0-9][0-9]"
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: Note: My date output produced a trailing space, which I had to strip.

Comment: excellent worked thanks your comment about the trailing space solved my problem. in my date declaration there is a space, i removed it and my script worked.  Thanks for all the responses and really quick as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make `fubar_file` an array to hold the matching log file names, and then use a loop to `gzip` them individually. Then presuming `AUS_DATE` contains `20150928`:

```
# FUBAR_DATE=$(date -d "days ago"  +"%Y%m%d ") # not needed for gzip
fubar_file=( /apps/fubar/logs/fubar.log.$AUS_DATE-[0-9][0-9] )
for i in ${fubar_file[@]}; do
    gzip "$i"
done
```

or if you do not need to preserve the filenames in the array for later use, just `gzip` the files with a for loop:

```
for i in /apps/fubar/logs/fubar.log.$AUS_DATE-[0-9][0-9]; do
    gzip "$i"
done
```

or, simply use `find` to match the files and `gzip` them:

```
find /apps/fubar/logs -type f -name "fubar.log.$AUS_DATE-[0-9][0-9]" -execdir gzip '{}' +
```

**Note:** all answers presume `AUS_DATE` contains `20150928`.